# Editing with CSS span selector

Tags: css

Im fairly new to CSS and have to modify my span selector to implement the following when I call on my spam tags:

- 24 point not pixel font
- underlined
- bold
- Tahoma font family

Right now I have this but it dosnt seem to be working

```
.test1 {
  font-family: Tahoma; 
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: Underlined, Bold; 
}
```

Comment: haha "spam" tags

Comment: can you paste your whole HTML and CSS code maybe I can  help?!

Comment: You have all the keywords, by googling each one you will understand each property and get your answer but by asking you will simply get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split out the bold and underline:

```css
.test1 {
  font-family: Tahoma; 
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold; /* this is font weight */
  text-decoration: underline; /* this is underline */
}
```

```html
<span class="test1">hello world</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
.test1 {
  font-family: Tahoma; 
  font-size: 24pt;
  text-decoration: underline; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

24pt if you want in points, if not 24px if you want in pixels

Answer (score 1):

Give all your `<span>`s the class `test1` as such:

```
<span class="test1">Content</span>
<span class="test1">Other content<span>
```

In your `test1` CSS class, add the `text-decoration` property for underline, as such:

```
.test1 {
    font-family: Tahoma; 
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Find all the CSS properties here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

Answer (score 0):

bold and underline can be achieved by 2 different styles: `font-weight` and `text-decoration`

```css
 
.test1 {
  font-family: Tahoma; 
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold; 
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<span class="test1">
test
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can't have two properties in same line!! Underline and bold are two different properties of element !!
Try this !!

```
.test1 { font-family: Tahoma; font-size: 24pt; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold; }
```